# Why is value set in input value is of type string only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I want to set state the value in setstate as integer in the in my reactjs component.
I am unable to do so since the value is not set as integer so in radio button its does not comes as checked.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   frequency: 1,
}
handleSelectChange(event) {

  this.setState({
    frequency: event.target.value
  })
};


<div className = "custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline"
onChange = {
    this.handleSelectChange.bind(this)
  } >
  <
  input type = "radio"
id = "oneTime"
value = "0"
name = "type"
onChange = {
  event => this.handleSelectChange(event)
}

checked = {
  this.state.frequency === "0"
}
className = "custom-control-input" / >
  <
  label className = "custom-control-label"
htmlFor = "oneTime" > {
    Labels.PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION.ONETIME
  } <
  /label> < /
div > <
  div className = "custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline" >
  <
  input type = "radio"
id = "continuous"
value = "1"
name = "type"
checked = {
  this.state.frequency === "1"
}
onChange = {
  event => this.handleSelectChange(event)
}
className = "custom-control-input" / >
  <
  label className = "custom-control-label"
htmlFor = "continuous" > {
    Labels.PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION.CONTINUOUS
  } 
  </label>
  </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I know we can set this by using defaultValue. But then it becomes uncontrolled which is not encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting value as string like

```
<input type="radio" value="1" />
```

Set it as integer

```
<input type="radio" value={1} />
```

Also try to use `===` while comparing if you want some value of your state to be strictly number, otherwise your comparisons won't be very strict

**Edit**

To make the radio button checked you can then set the `checked` attr of radio by comparing it to the value of state

```
<input type="radio" checked={this.state.frequency === 1} value={1} />
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but radio button does not get checked when I click on it.

Comment: it won't be checked based on value but on checked property, let me edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the value like:

```
<input type="radio"
 checked={this.state.frequency === 1}
 value={this.state.frequency || 0} />
```

You already noticed from another answer that `value="0"` will represent the string `0` while `value={0}` will represent the integer `0`.